# SQL Server 2008 trying to make it more secure with views and schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, security

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this,

I am mucking around in our sandbox and I am trying to find the best way to make our database more secure.

The issue we have is that we have 3 databases and we require information from each (using unions and views). We also have external shipping companies and merchants that need to have access to certain information in our database.

My thought was to create a separate database that had different merchant schemas (called `MVIEW`). Then create views within these schemas depending on what the merchants need. The views would then access the data from the other servers (the problem is that this would require the merchants to have `SELECT` permissions on the other servers etc.)

So at this point I thought it wise to create merchant schema's in each database and make views in there that would access the necessary information within the database, and then have the `HVIEW` database access those views. This way I could give the merchants select on just those schemas.

The problem still stands that the error says that the permission is denied and the user does not have access to the schemas that the view is trying to look at.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The **main** question is: do these merchants really need **database-level** access? Couldn't you hide all those databases behind a **service layer** (with WCF) and just define that way who gets to see and use what?

Comment: Thanks marc for answering, the truth is currently a lot of them use ODBC and excel, so creating views and telling them just to do SELECT * FROM view would be the simplest way to go. and other external shipments do something similar since they use an ERP. I am not as familiar with dealing with multiple db's and joining them together.

Comment: Perhaps you can replicate the required tables on each of the three servers to a single server where views can be created without permission issues.

Comment: I agree, Ron but it seems like a little bit of overkill on work, since what they may need may chance and new merchants may arrive as well. I was really hoping to go with views on this, but it looks like it may not be a good option.

Comment: You can achieve something like this with impersonate but I'd go with @rontornambe for two other reasons. One you could optimise it to their use. two if they do a cartesian product from on five big views, you won't watch your entire system grind to a halt.

Comment: Interesting Tony, thanks for your opinion. I will research more into it.

Comment: How large are the tables and the usual select that the external clients perform? do they require historic data or it can be limited to a small set. The question is, because maybe you could create some kind of tool or dll that the external people could use from VBA or something like that? Or maybe a Macro to populate Excel from a Web Service? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc539928%28v=office.12%29.aspx) just.. wanted to point out more options :)

Comment: Thanks Leo, they are great ideas, however the population is rather large (could be over 100k) but never ends up being large due to the view being dynamic. The merchant can add filters to the view, and the filter changes depending what certain things are needed. ( Sorry if it is vague.)

Answer (score 0):

Give them all access only to some views, but not to the data tables. And in the views, refer to the user login id. So behind the scenes, hidden within the view, you will be restricting their access with WHERE clauses

Example: select . . . . where supplierUser=SYSTEM_USER

Example: select . . . . where externalAccess=1 and SYSTEM_USER  in (select names from tbl_externalUsers)

Comment: Thanks for responding Chris, I have honestly never tried this. It seems like a very interesting approach. I will test it out. Thanks again!